# Data import issue for RSS in Svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

novice here, trying to experiment with showing my blog and have managed to get an RSS feed in VS code terminal on a page.server.js however can't figure out how to use it.

Here's the code: In data.js

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { parseStringPromise } from 'xml2js';

export async function fetchRSSFeed(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const rssText = await response.text();
    const parsedResult = await parseStringPromise(rssText);
    const items = parsedResult.rss.channel[0].item;
    return items.map(item => ({
        title: item.title[0],
        link: item.link[0]
    }));
}
```

In +page.server.js

```
import { fetchRSSFeed } from './data.js';

export async function load() {
        const rssFeedUrl = 'myBlog';
        const articles = await fetchRSSFeed(rssFeedUrl);
        console.log(articles);

    return {
        props: {
            articles

        }
    };

}
```

and here's the +page.svelte

```
    <script>
        export let articles = [];
        console.log("Why are there no articles???", articles);
      </script>

      <div id="container">
        <div class="about">
          <p>thoughts available on substack</p>
        </div>
        <section>
      <h2>recent posts</h2>
      <hr />
      <div class="posts">
        {#each articles as { title, link }}
          <a href={link} target="_blank">
            <div class="post">
              <h3>{title}</h3>
            </div>
          </a>
        {/each}
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance, big love x

I'd like to make an RSS feed in Svelte, I've tried adding the data.js as an extra route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how [data loading](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#page-data) works.
The object returned is always passed to a property called `data`, there is no `props`.

```js
return { articles };
```

```js
export let data; // data.articles
```